# Ruby xml rpc error handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model

```
class Car
  @@RPCServer = XMLRPC::Client.new("localhost", "/", 8080)

  def self.count
    @@RPCServer.call("cars.count")
  end
end
```

If server is not running on localhost:8080 I've got a Errno::ECONNREFUSED error.
I want to display an error message to user, how can a handle this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to trap the error in order to handle the exception in the way your application needs. The following code will trap this Exception. If you need to trap other exceptions then you can include multiple rescue clauses.

```
class Car
  @@RPCServer = XMLRPC::Client.new("localhost", "/", 8080)

  def self.count
    begin
      @@RPCServer.call("cars.count")
    rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
      # Do Appropriate handling here
    end
  end
end
```